# ASP.Net - Open a PDF using a web method

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

Just wondering if it's possible to open a PDF using a web method called using AJAX? The file to open is stored in a temp directory on the server.

Does anyone have any suggestions how this can be achieved?

Thanks all!

Comment: If files are huge and you need to somehow show the progress of the _download_, then you should refer to here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676348/allow-user-to-download-file-using-ajax

Comment: Any reason why a simple link won't do?

Comment: Are you trying to read a pdf in the server side?

Answer (score 0):

Oded has given you the best solutions but, if you still want to do it that way, here it goes:

You can use this jquery [plugin](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_plugin_for_requesting_ajax_like_file_downloads/).

Your web page would have an hyperlink:

```
<a id="PrintAjaxReport" href="javascript:{}">Print report Ajax</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#PrintAjaxRepor").click(function() {
         $.download('PdfReport.aspx', "filename=mySpreadsheet", "POST");
     });
});
```

PdfReport.aspx

```
public partial class PdfReport : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var pdfDocumentName = Request.Params["filename"].ToString() + ".pdf";
        var myReport = "Razor Syntax Quick Reference.pdf";

        var FileName = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~"), "Temp"), myReport);

        Response.Clear();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.ClearContent();

        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + pdfDocumentName);
        Response.TransmitFile(FileName);
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

You can find a sample (OpenPDFjQuery) [here](https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=669adf1af64df389&sc=documents&id=669ADF1AF64DF389!155).